# Conditional stage execution on PR raise even Azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My current project structure has two folders, each having its own `package.xml` and individual deployment scripts.

```
src
src1 (added Newley)
```

**Branch name:** develop

**Current policy:** Runs SRC validation on a PR raise event

Problem statement: Now that I have added SRC1, I want to have a PR policy such that:

- Whenever a PR is raised, if the PR contains changes in src1 only then it should run SRC1 validation
- Whenever a PR is raised, if the PR contains changes in Src only then it should run src validation
- Whenever a PR is raised, if PR contains changes in both, then both pipelines should be run.

Is there a way to implement this use case in Azure DevOps/VSTS tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a single build validation pipeline with multiple jobs. In this pipeline, you can run `git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1` in a script task to get the changed folders. And then use [dependencies and conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for the multiple jobs.

See below example: There are three jobs in below yaml pipeline.

The first job **GetFolder** will run the git commands to get the changed folders. Then set the variable `SCR1Folder` to `true` if SCR1 folder is changed, and set the variable `SCR2Folder` to `true` if SCR2 folder is changed. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable) for more information about set output variables in scripts.

The second job **SRC1** is dependent on job **GetFolder**. And It will be executed after
job **GetFolder**, and on the condition if variable `SCR1Folder` is `true` `eq(dependencies.GetFolder.outputs['Flag.SCR1Folder'], 'true')`

The third job **SRC2** is dependent on job **GetFolder** and job "SRC1". It will be executed on the condition if variable `SCR2Folder` is `true` `eq(dependencies.GetFolder.outputs['Flag.SCR2Folder'], 'true')`, and it will run after job **GetFolder** and job "SRC1"

```
trigger: none

pool:
 vmImage: windows-latest

jobs:
- job: GetFolder
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      $folders= git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1
      $folders
      if($folders -cmatch ".*/*SCR1/.*"){
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SCR1Folder;isOutput=true]true" 
        }
      if($folders -cmatch ".*/*SCR2/.*"){
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SCR2Folder;isOutput=true]true" 
         }
    name: Flag

- job: SRC1
  dependsOn: GetFolder
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.GetFolder.outputs['Flag.SCR1Folder'], 'true'))
  steps:
  - powershell: echo "run src1 validation"
   
- job: SRC2
  dependsOn: 
  - GetFolder
  - SRC1
  condition: and(succeeded('GetFolder'),eq(dependencies.GetFolder.outputs['Flag.SCR2Folder'], 'true'))
  steps:
  - powershell: echo "run src2 validation"
```

I tested above yaml pipeline. If only src1 folder is changed. Then job GetFolder and job SRC1 will run and job SRC2 will be skiped.

If If only src2 folder is changed. Then job GetFolder and job SRC2 will run and job SRC1 will be skiped.

If both folders are changed job SRC2 will be run after job SRC1.

Comment: This works like a charm. Although there is an observation that in case we run both src src1, it is checking out the repo 3 times. Once for Get folder, Secondly for Src, thirdly for src1. Can we optimize this script so as to clone only once during the pipeline? As with the current setup, it is taking about thrice the actual clone time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using cloud hosted agents. each job will use a [fresh new virtual machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#microsoft-hosted-agents).  If job src and src1 need the code source. You will have to clone the repo triple times. If src and src1 donnot need the source code. You can add [checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#checkout) step to skip clone the repo.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create 2 builds:

1. Run src validation
2. Run src1 validation

Create a build validation policy in the PR and filter the builds with the `path filter`:

[image]

The above its fir src, add one more with corresponding filter.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#path-filters) more info.

Comment: I guess this will work on PR merge event. I am interested in PR raise event and the PR should not allowed to be merged if the PR validation policies are not met. Please let me know if this is a wrong understanding. Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: Hi @B.TAnand, it's exactly what you need, it's in the PR raise event - in the build validation policy the merge will not happen if the build failed (build failed == validation policies are not met).

Comment: Hi @Shayki, let's consider a scenario wherein only src has been changed. Despite of the src validation passing, we will not be able to merge the PR's as in the policies we have added 2 other pipelines (src1/both) as well right?

Comment: No, we could merge because we added "path filters" to each pipeline.

Comment: okay, thank you. Let me try this one out. Shall vote for the correct answer if it works. Thank you for your time on this

Comment: I added it to the policy, but the issue there was if there were changes in both src and src1 all 3 pipelines would get trigged. We handled it by keeping 1 for src only and 1 for src1. However, is it possible for us to add dependency between policies? E.g. : Execute src1 build policy only after src build policy has successfully passed?

Comment: Great, I wanted to write you this solution :) regarding the dependency, is not out of the box.

Comment: regarding the dependency, is it not possible?

Comment: you can queue the second build after the first build passed with build completion trigger: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml or with https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks

Comment: Well, I think this is similar to upstream downstream concept of Jenkins, However at the policy level we want both the pipelines to be executable independently along with if there are changes in both src and src1 then the former policy should execute first followed by the latter.

Comment: it could be achieved with a PS script, but it's for another question....